# onClick on a div containing a component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a state and a onClick function. when i connect it to the div containing a button (which is imported component), the on click does not function on the button, if i make the div bigger i can click outside the button and the call gets picked up. I have attempted to put the onclick into a prop for the button and add an on click event on the imported component button with the prop, but this does not work either.

Thank you for your time

**APP:** (I have left the div on click and the props onClick attempts below, of course only one option is required)

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ContactForm.module.scss';
import {
  BoxHeader,
  Button,
  Date,
  Input,
  Select,
  Submit,
  Textarea
} from '../../elements';

              </div>
              <div>
                <Date label="Date of Birth" />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.button}>
                <Button innerHTML="Next >" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.contactBlock} >
            <div className={styles.header} onClick={this.onStepThreeClick} >
              <BoxHeader title="Step 3: Final Comments" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles[this.state.stepThree]}>
                <div className={styles.textArea}>
                  <Textarea label="Comments" /> 
                </div>
                <div className={styles.submit}>
                  <Submit innerHTML="Next >" />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

**Button:**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import styles from'./Button.module.scss';

export const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button className={styles.button} onClick={props.stepVisibility} > {props.innerHTML} </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

**CSS (for the swapped class only:**

```
.stepHide {
  height: 0em;
  background: rgb(209, 209, 209);
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

  .button {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}

.stepShow {
  height: 10em;
  background: rgb(209, 209, 209);
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
  padding: 2.5em;
  margin: -.8em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

  .button {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    z-index:2;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"the on click does not function on the button"* How do you determine that? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i put the on click on the imported button component sending it a prop. once i did it, i click the button, the button wobbles but the class for the <div> under BoxHeader does not swap to reveal it.

Comment: added css code to the question for the swapped class

Comment: Have you tried swapping the `<button>` with a `<div>`. In my experience the `<button>` can be somewhat tricky at times.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, that works. Just odd doesnt work with button??? Is this normal? Not to work with the <button> element?

Comment: The `<button>` element has some native functionality that can differ based on where it is used, for instance in your case, inside a form (never bothered to learn exactly what the implementation of the button does). So I have chosen to not use button at all and rather use divs with click handlers, and rather add accessibility attributes to the div telling screen readers etc that it is a button.